# How to have stroke on all all sides but bottom using UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created a bezier path with:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
          byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
```

Is there a way to only stroke 3 of the 4 sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by creating your own bezier path. Here's how we did this back in the days. You can apply/stroke this path using a CoreGraphics context. Should be easy enough. I've adapted the sample to draw a rounded rect without the bottom part.

```
CGFloat width = 100;
CGFloat height = 200;
CGFloat radius = 10;
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable ();

CGPathMoveToPoint (path, nil, width, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, nil, width, height - radius);
CGPathAddArcToPoint (path, nil, width, height, width - radius, height, radius);
CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, nil, radius, height);
CGPathAddArcToPoint (path, nil, 0, height, 0, height - radius, radius);
CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, nil, 0, 0);

CGPathCloseSubpath (path);
```